# mySQL trigger - error when declaring variable

Tags: mysql, trigger, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin and I am trying to declare a variable but it throws an error.

Using the following code, it works just fine:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE new.val=old.val) THEN
    SET new.val = 0;
END IF
```

But when I try to declare a variable, it won't work. For example:

```
DECLARE d INT;
SET d=new.val;
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE old.val=d) THEN
    SET new.val = 0;
END IF
```

I also tried @d instead of d.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you show the whole trigger code - and the exact error you got.